# jquery toggle with arrows problem

Tags: jquery, toggle

I am trying to add down arrows image when expanding and right arrow image when its not expanded, which work fine wiht the code below.

THE problem is when u collapse the block again it doesnt remove the down arrow image. when its collapsed i wanted the down arrow replaced by the right arrow image.

thanks

```
            $('#title h4').removeClass('DownArrow ');
            $('#title h4').addClass('RightArrow '); 
            $('#title').click(function() {
              $('#d-form').slideToggle("slow");
              $('#title h4').addClass('DownArrow ');            
            });


<div id="title"> <h4><a href="#">Dental</a></h4></div>
<div id="d-form">
some stuff
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just use `.toggleClass()`<sup>([DOCS](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/))</sup>:

```
$('#title h4').removeClass('DownArrow ');
$('#title h4').addClass('RightArrow ');
$('#title').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#d-form').slideToggle("slow");

    $('#title h4').toggleClass('RightArrow');
    $('#title h4').toggleClass('DownArrow');
});
```

I also added `preventDefault()` to your click event so that the hash isn't loaded into the href.

[See example →](http://jsfiddle.net/6SfWy/)

Answer (score 0):

Use toggleClass instead

```
          $('#title h4').toggleClass('DownArrow');
          $('#title h4').toggleClass('RightArrow');
```

Working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XeNSj/)